# Help with - Apex to call a URL whenever a URL is populated in a URL field

Tags: apex

I'm working on building an apex which will trigger whenever a URL field(X470_Quote_Link__c) has a value in it.

I need an apex to call this URL (this URL will send an email and also adds a record in a separate database) whenever there is a URL populated in URL field(X470_Quote_Link__c)

This is what I tried -

```
public without sharing class InsideSalesCallout implements 

 public static void Outboundcall(
            List<Lead> scope){

  ID[] ids = new List<ID>();
  String url = label.EndpointConfig;
  String body;

  for(Lead l : scope){
      if(l.X470_Quote_Link__c!='' || l.X470_Quote_Link__c!=null){
          ids.add(l.id);
      }
  }

   if (!ids.isEmpty()) {
       body =  X470_Quote_Link__c; // I know this is not the right way of refrencing the URL field.
       HTTPRequestSenderURL.sendHTTPRequestURL(url, body);
    }
  }

}
```

and this is the httpcallout class -

```
 global class HTTPRequestSenderURL{

 @future (callout=true)

 Public static void sendHTTPRequestURL(String url, String body){

    Http http = new Http();

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setEndpoint(url);

    req.setBody(body);

    req.setMethod('POST');

    try {

        res = http.send(req);

    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {

        System.debug('CalloutException: '+ e);

        System.debug(res.toString());

     }

   }

}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I haven't completed my code, in the first class above I need to get value of URL field(X470_Quote_Link__c) to 'body'  how do I do that ?

Comment: @Sanjay - Then please update your question with your actual question and be very clear about what it is your are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the field the same way you're already referencing it in your for loop.  Or better yet, save the values of this field during that loop, in the first place:

```
Map<Id, String> externalUrlMap = new Map<Id, String>();

for(Lead l : scope){
    if (l.X470_Quote_Link__c!='' || l.X470_Quote_Link__c!=null) {
      externalUrlMap.put(l.Id, l.X470_Quote_Link__c);
    }
}

if (!externalUrlMap.isEmpty()) {
   // You now have a map of all the lead IDs which reference an external URL, and the referenced URLs.
   // You can assemble and process them as you wish.
   // It really depends what you're trying to do
   // For example:
   String body = '';
   for (Id leadId : externalUrlMap.keySet()) {
       body += 'Id: ' + leadId + '  Url: ' + externalUrlMap.get(leadId) + '\n';
   HTTPRequestSenderURL.sendHTTPRequestURL(url, body);
}
```

}